# Why is float() not floatifying?

Tags: python, floating-point

I've been reading that in Python, using float() on a numerical string can produce the number inside of the string. So for instance, doing something like:

```
num_str = '0.2237'
num = float(num_str)

print(num)
```

I expect to have 0.2237 as my output. However, when I try this, it gives me the following TypeError:

> 'str' object is not callable

Why isn't float() "floatifying" my number string?

Comment: Because you must have assigned a string to `float` previously.

Comment: `del float; print("floatifyfaction ready!")`

Comment: @gorzardfu, I just run the code you have provided, and it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce. That's not how the builtin behaves. You must have shadowed `float` with a new variable. `del float` to expose the builtin version and try again.

Comment: It is the answer, but there's a dupe somewhere

Comment: Thanks! That worked. It wasn't even working when I did this in a new .py file. Once I ran it with del float it worked, and then it worked after I erased del float. (I have minimal programming experience by the way, so thanks for your patience.)